# Query acceleration in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This code collects and brings in results in 1 million records.
This process takes a lot of time to show up.
How can I make this faster?

```
$urunler       = $db->get_results("SELECT urunid,urunadi FROM sf_urun01 WHERE sil!=2");
foreach ($urunler as $urun ){


$a   = $db->get_var("SELECT SUM(tonaj) FROM sf_urun10 WHERE urunid='$urun->urunid' AND (durumu='GIRIS' OR durumu='HATALI') AND cariid > 5 AND  sil !=2");
$b   = $db->get_var("SELECT SUM(tonaj) FROM sf_urun10 WHERE urunid='$urun->urunid'AND (durumu='GIRIS' OR durumu='HATALI') AND cariid < 5 AND istifyeri!='FASON'  AND   sil !=2");
$c   = $db->get_var("SELECT SUM(tonaj) FROM sf_urun10 WHERE urunid='$urun->urunid' AND durumu='HATALI' AND cariid < 5 AND  sil !=2");

$d   = $db->get_var("SELECT SUM(tonaj) FROM sf_urun10 WHERE urunid='$urun->urunid' AND istifyeri='FASON' AND (durumu='GIRIS' OR durumu='HATALI') AND cariid > 5 AND  sil !=2");


/*
Using Datatable 
*/

}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: You could write those 4 queries into the main query by using joins, and run EXPLAIN select on the statements to ensure you have correct columns indexed.

Comment: Questions regarding query optimization might be better asked (and answered) at [dba.se]. Take a look at that Stackexchange site.

Comment: It would b better if you can explain some of your business logic behind

Comment: ensure you have index set for `urunid` column

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could merge all those queries into one, which ought to be faster:

```
SELECT urunid,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN (durumu='GIRIS' OR durumu='HATALI') AND cariid > 5 THEN tonaj
        ELSE 0 END) 
    AS a,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN (durumu='GIRIS' OR durumu='HATALI') AND cariid < 5 AND istifyeri!='FASON' THEN tonaj
        ELSE 0 END) 
    AS b,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN durumu='HATALI' AND cariid < 5 THEN tonaj
        ELSE 0 END)
    AS c,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN istifyeri='FASON' AND (durumu='GIRIS' OR durumu='HATALI') AND cariid > 5 THEN tonaj
        ELSE 0 END)
    AS d
FROM sf_urun10
WHERE sil !=2
GROUP BY urunid
```

This will give a table of the form

```
urunid  a   b   c   d
1       56  252 15  76
etc.
```